# Modifying labels (x,y,z) in heatmap on plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to rename labels in a heatmap. for example:
instead of the label says "x:", I want the label to say "Hour:"
instead of the label says "y:", I want the label to say "Day:"

```
Library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(z = volcano, colors = colorRamp(c("red", "green")), type = "heatmap")
```

[image]
furthermore, it would be useful, for example if we use a transformation of data in order to intensify contrast, still the html interactive label show real data.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb0GR.png)

Comment: Today it's not possible to customize this hover text for the `heatmap` trace but we have an issue open to add this functionality: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3437

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
library(plotly)
dat <- expand.grid(x = 1:nrow(volcano), y = 1:ncol(volcano))
dat$z <- c(volcano)

plot_ly(height = 500) %>%
  layout(autosize = FALSE, 
         xaxis=list(title = "Hour", titlefont = list(size=20)),
         yaxis=list(title = "Day", titlefont = list(size=20))) %>%
  add_trace(data = dat, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "heatmap",
            hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste("Hour:", dat$x,
                          "<br> Day:", dat$y,
                          "<br> z:", dat$z))
```

[image]